# Can an RPG program call something external, ie: a webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ibm-midrange, rpg

Is there a way for an RPG program to call a web service? I would prefer an ASP.Net web service but would be fine with a winform app or a web page.

I'm wanting make an internet service available to the iseries by creating a gateway.

Comment: For a couple of seconds there I was wondering why this was a problem for Role Playing Games, when eventually the dust blew off some 20+ year old neurons and I thought "Oh, that RPG, OK then . . ." :)

Comment: @Binary, the tag explains that it is NOT roleplaying games. Though some still use as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scott Klement has written about how to do this.  Our RPG developers have used his articles and call our .NET web services in many of their newer programs.

Start here: http://www.scottklement.com/presentations/#HTTPAPI

Comment: Have you found any problems with this approach with more complex scenarios?

Comment: @Thorbj0rn Ravn Andersen - The only problem we came across was a limitation of the number of characters in the web service function names.  Some of our functions had longer names than the iSeries would support, so on the .NET side, we made functions with shorter names that simply called the corresponding function with the long name.  For example, a function named LogCallToHeatViaApi() was too long, so we wrote a method called ApiLogCall(), which internally just called the original.